# Vertical spacing in align environment

Tags: align

I see several solutions for adding vertical space to an align environment, but I want to subtract vertical space. When compiled, the following code shows much more space between the text and the overbrace than between the text and the underbrace. It looks odd. It's possible that my \intertext approach is wrong, but I don't know any other way to get what I want. Is there a fix?

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\intertext{\hspace{6cm} $m$ terms} \\
\frac{x^m}{x^n}  = \frac{\overbrace{x \times x \times x \times x \cdots \times x}}
                        {\underbrace{x \times x \times x \cdots \times x}}. \\
\intertext{\hspace{6cm} $n$ terms}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use `\\ ` after intertext

Comment: but `\intertext` is the wrong tool to use here, it is designed for unaligned sentence between the lines not to position an annotation by hand spacing with `\hspace` use `\underbrace` and `\overbrace` for _n_ terms

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I knew there was a better way.  Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I don't usually add line breaks to intertext, that was an editing error that I didn't spot. But it was a lucky error since without it the result would have "looked okay" and I wouldn't have posted. Then I wouldn't have learned several useful things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use properly `\overbrace` and `\underbrace`.

And don't use `align` for single equation; also, never end `align` with `\\`.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{x^m}{x^n} =
\frac{\overbrace{x \times x \times x \times x \times \dots \times x}^{m\text{ terms}}}
     {\underbrace{x \times x \times x \times \dots \times x}_{n\text{ terms}}}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\dots` usually chooses the correct kind of ellipsis (and you missed a couple of `\times`).

In general, it's best to brace an `\overbrace` or `\underbrace` construct; in this case they're the only items in the numerator and denominator, so there's no need of outer braces.

Comment: I'd never have thought of a putting a sub/sup on a construct like a brace. Also, I didn't know \ldots was so clever!  Thanks for the complete response.